# Karate - How to use sleep for scenarios?

Tags: unit-testing, karate

I have scenario when i need to use sleep. But when I run this function I get ERROR. It working previously, but I didn't run this test long time ago and when I run this test again I get this error.
This is one of my scenarios:

```
  Scenario: test sleep
    * def sleep = function(pause){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(pause*1000) }
    * url 'http://someURL:8080/api/v1/'

    Given path 'endpoint/' + 470538
    When method get
    Then status 200

    * call sleep(20)
```

Sleep function looks like working, but in the end of test I get test fail:

```
not a callable feature or js function: [type: NULL, value: null]
```

Could you help me please to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for the `call`, please read the docs:

```
Scenario:
* def sleep = function(pause){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(pause*1000) }
* print 'before'
* sleep(5)
* print 'after'
```

That said - yes, `call` would work, but like this:

```
Scenario:
* def sleep = function(pause){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(pause*1000) }
* print 'before'
* call sleep 5
* print 'after'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.
Could you please share link for a docs.

Comment: When setting the function in a different feature file, the call and non-call sleep options do not appear to work, resulting in `01: sleep(25)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: execute on {value={}} failed due to: Message not supported.
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)` or `* call sleep 25
not a callable feature or js function: [type: MAP, value: {}]`.  Is it possible to set this function in a spearate called feature or does it need to be placed in every file where it is used?