# Functions declared in separate feature do not appear to be accessible

Tags: karate

When setting the [sleep function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894108/karate-how-to-use-sleep-for-scenarios) in a different feature file, the call and non-call sleep options do not appear to work, resulting in the following errors:

- sleep(25)

```
01: sleep(25) 
<<<< org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: execute on {value={}} failed due to: Message not supported. - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

or

- call sleep 25

```
* call sleep 25 not a callable feature or js function: [type: MAP, value: {}].
```

Is it possible to set this function in a spearate called feature or does it need to be placed in every file where it is used? Would the expectation be to setup a js, and then called within each file (seems like extra overhead)?
We are also expanding our tests and creating functions for random string, random ints, and uuids, but we would like to do this once rather than in every file, where needed.  We tried to set these up in the config, but [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035022/defining-two-o-more-functions-in-karate-config-js), that this was not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to need to place the function in every feature file to be able to use the function globally. You can just make a JS file that includes your sleep function and use call read in any feature file to invoke your function.

Create a file named sleep.js with the following code

```
function (params) {
print("Sleeping for ", params.timeInMs, "ms")
java.lang.Thread.sleep(params.timeInMs)
}
```

And then in your feature file you can call and use the function like so to sleep for 25 seconds or however long you need.

```
* call read('classpath:sleep.js') { timeInMs: 25000 }
```